# Optimizing computation in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, optimization

I have a list having 900 elements and I want to take the combination of every element with another element and then process them so basically, I have matrix of 900X900.
Presently I'm doing like:

```
Col_List = [l1,l2.......l900] # l1, l2 are list of columns in a dataframe

Sim_Dict = {}


with open('list.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(Col_List, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    for i, LO in enumerate(Col_List):
        LO_list = [LO for x in range(len(Col_List))]
        pool = mp.Pool()
        Sim_Dict[LO] = pool.map(Similarity, zip(LO_list,Col_List))
        if(i%25 == 0):
            print('done:', LO)
with open('dictionary.pickle2', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(Sim_Dict, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
end = datetime.datetime.now()
print("timeTaken: ", end-start)

def Similarity(lists):
    """
    Similarity between item1 and item2
    Input: item i and item j
    Output: Average Similarity score between two items
    """
    item1, item2 = lists[0], lists[1]
    if (item1==item2):
        return 1
    else:
        dataframe = pd.read_csv('df_Student_User')
        df_test = dataframe[(dataframe.loc[:, item1] != dataframe.loc[:, item2])
                            & (dataframe.loc[:, item1].notnull())
                            & (dataframe.loc[:, item2].notnull())
                           ].loc[:, [item1, item2]]
        df_test[item1] = pd.to_datetime(df_test[item1])  # converting to date time
        df_test[item2] = pd.to_datetime(df_test[item2])
        # Delta_t
        df_test['Delta_t'] = abs(((df_test.loc[:, item1] -
                                   df_test.loc[:, item2]
                                   ).dt.total_seconds() / 3600).astype(int))
        # Delta D
        df_test['Delta_D'] = abs(df_test[[item1, item2]].min(axis=1) - 
                                 dt.datetime.now().date()
                                 ).astype('timedelta64[h]').astype('int')
        df_test['S_ij'] = 1 / (df_test.Delta_t + df_test.Delta_D)
        SimScore = df_test.S_ij.sum(axis=0)
        del df_test
        return SimScore
```

can I optimize it more? in order to return result fast?
as for 100X100 it approach takes around 10 minutes and with simple maths, for 900X900 it would take around 13 hours.

Similarity() takes around 0.1400 seconds to find similarity between two random items.

Comment: could you check your indentation? It seems odd.

Comment: @MSeifert - I tried to fix the indentation, I'm afraid it's unsalvageably ugly...

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise we have to guess what's going on in your code. For example, what are `l1`, `l2`, ... the elements of `col_list`? What is `tt`? What is `function`? Your function `Similarity` is not called in your code. What is its argument? Is it a list of two list? You reload your .csv file every time `Similarity` is called. You should load it one time outside the scope of `Similartity`.

Comment: @MaxPowers I have edited the code